# NullPointerException on removing item from ClusterManager with NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm

Tags: java, android, google-maps, markerclusterer

I'm developing an Android App using Google Map and clustering.

**I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception when I try to remove an Item from the cluster manager.**

```
  E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.remove(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.google.maps.android.quadtree.PointQuadTree.remove(PointQuadTree.java:176)
        at com.google.maps.android.quadtree.PointQuadTree.remove(PointQuadTree.java:171)
        at com.google.maps.android.quadtree.PointQuadTree.remove(PointQuadTree.java:153)
        at com.google.maps.android.clustering.algo.NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm.removeItem(NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm.java:95)
        at com.google.maps.android.clustering.algo.PreCachingAlgorithmDecorator.removeItem(PreCachingAlgorithmDecorator.java:61)
        at com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterManager.removeItem(ClusterManager.java:161)
        at com.company.myApp.controllers.MapClusterManager.removeItem(MapClusterManager.java:72)
```

The code that is throwing the exception is the following:

```
  if(clusterManager.getAlgorithm().getItems().contains(mapClusterItem)) {
        clusterManager.removeItem(mapClusterItem); // <-- NPE here
        clusterManager.cluster();
  }
```

**As you can see I'm actually checking the existence of the item before the deletion.**

The clustering setup follows:

```
    clusterManager = new ClusterManager<MapClusterItem>(context, googleMap);
    algo = new NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm<MapClusterItem>();
    clusterManager.setAlgorithm(algo);
```

**The problem is that PointQuadTree.remove(double x, double y, T item) (Google Library) throws the Exception.
Does anyone know how to solve it?**

The `GridBasedAlgoritm` doesn't fit my case. I want to use the

> NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm

.

I'm using the cluster library from Google Maps Utils.

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.+'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in the library, and it's going to be delivered a fixed version soon as said here:

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/348

Comment: It seems I have the same problem now - is that possible something was introduced again in the library?

Comment: Can you provide more details? The https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils library still gets to be updated but has not been modified for the code that was causing this issue since many time.

Comment: I have added my issue on GitHub issue tracker, please take a look. Basically I get java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference while having more that 1000 elements for my ClusterManager

Comment: It would be more easy to check at the issue you're reporting if it would be possible to be on a new question as it is possibly not the same of the current one.

Comment: Sure, did open a new issue: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/1015#issue-1032456395

Comment: Try to look for a solution on your repo issue link as it's probably not a bug in your code.